# Kotlin "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied" on Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to pass data from RecyclerView inside fragment to new activity, but "putExtra" displaying error like this :

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments
> supplied

**Fragment.kt**

class NewsFragment : Fragment() {

```
    private lateinit var adapter : NewsAdapter
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var newsArrayList : ArrayList<News>

    lateinit var imageId : Array<Int>
    lateinit var heading : Array<String>
    lateinit var news : Array<String>

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false)


    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        dataInitialize()

        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.moodyCategory_RV)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        adapter = NewsAdapter(newsArrayList)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(object : NewsAdapter.onItemClickListener {
            override fun onItemClick( position: Int) {

                val i = Intent (activity, NewsDetailActivity::class.java)
                i.putExtra("heading", newsArrayList[position], heading)
                i.putExtra("imageId", newsArrayList[position], imageId)
                i.putExtra( "news", news[position])
                startActivity(i)

            }
        })


    }


    private fun dataInitialize() {

        newsArrayList = arrayListOf<News>()
        imageId = arrayOf(
            R.drawable.a,
            R.drawable.b,
            R.drawable.c,
            R.drawable.d,
            R.drawable.e,
            R.drawable.f,
            R.drawable.g,
            R.drawable.h,
            R.drawable.i,
            R.drawable.j,
        )

        heading= arrayOf(
            getString(R.string.head_1),
            getString(R.string.head_2),
            getString(R.string.head_3),
            getString(R.string.head_4),
            getString(R.string.head_5),
            getString(R.string.head_6),
            getString(R.string.head_7),
            getString(R.string.head_8),
            getString(R.string.head_9),
            getString(R.string.head_10),
        )

        news = arrayOf(
            getString(R.string.news_a),
            getString(R.string.news_b),
            getString(R.string.news_c),
            getString(R.string.news_d),
            getString(R.string.news_e),
            getString(R.string.news_f),
            getString(R.string.news_g),
            getString(R.string.news_h),
            getString(R.string.news_i),
            getString(R.string.news_j),
        )

        for (i in imageId.indices){

            val news = News(imageId[i], heading[i])
            newsArrayList.add(news)
        }
    }
```

**Adapter**

```
class NewsAdapter(private val newslist: ArrayList<NewsModel>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.CategoryViewHolder>() {


    private lateinit var mListener: onItemClickListener

    interface onItemClickListener {

        fun onItemClick(position: Int)


    }

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: onItemClickListener) {

        mListener = listener

    }
    

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CategoryViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.item_news_layout,
            parent, false
        )
        return CategoryViewHolder(itemView, mListener) 
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CategoryViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = newslist[position]
        holder.titleImage.setImageResource(currentItem.titleImage)
        holder.tvHeading.text = currentItem.heading
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return newslist.size
    }


    class CategoryViewHolder(itemView: View, listener: onItemClickListener) : 
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val titleImage: ShapeableImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_image)
        val tvHeading: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeading)

        init {

            itemView.setOnClickListener{
                listener.onItemClick(adapterPosition)

            }

        }

    }


}
```

Someone help me please, and thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Removed tag `android-studio`. That tag is for questions/issues about the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: Did you mean to do `i.putExtra("heading", newsArrayList[position].heading)` in there? (dot, not comma). Or just `i.putExtra("heading", heading[position])`?

Answer (score 0):

```
  i.putExtra("heading", newsArrayList[position], heading)
  i.putExtra("imageId", newsArrayList[position], imageId)
```

There is no such a possibility to pass two arguments with one key at once.
Bundle is a key-value data structure and here you have one key and two values. If you really need to pass an array (heading/imageId) and a data model (newsArrayList[position]) through your intent, you should create a data class which will include both and pass it as a [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable)

As an example

```
@Parcelize
data class NewsModel(
    val news: String,
    val heading: Array<String>
): Parcelable {
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as NewsModel

        if (news != other.news) return false
        if (!heading.contentEquals(other.heading)) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = news.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + heading.contentHashCode()
        return result
    }
}
```

And then

```
val i = Intent(activity, NewsDetailActivity::class.java)
val model = newsArrayList[position]
val headingModel = NewsModel(model, heading)
val imageModel = NewsModel(model, imageId)
i.putExtra("heading", headingModel)
i.putExtra("imageId", imageModel)
i.putExtra("news", news[position])
```

Comment: nice, now the problem is solved. thanks! :)